# Ubuntu Studio: installing updates, but no admin password, done in a second

Tags: update-manager, ubuntu-studio

In Ubuntu Studio 22.04, Discover will tell me it has updates some quantity greater than zero, but list only a single item. When I click "Update All" I'm not prompted for a password and the update happens almost instantly, followed by a prompt to restart. What's happening? Is it actually updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the difference between the described behavior and my other PCs was in System Settings -> Software Update.

Update software: Automatically
Use offline updates: checked

With those two settings, updates happen much faster, and, yes, the system is updating correctly.